# jQuery AJAX JSON dataType Conversion

Tags: ajax, jquery, types, jsonp

Hopefully that title isn't *too* cryptic. What's happening is I have a jQuery AJAX script that I'm trying to use to access an API on a remote server, which returns a JSON response. However, the API returns the JSON as MIME type "text/html" (in the response header) instead of "application/json". It would seem obvious that I simply need to change the returned content type from text to JSON, to make the AJAX call interpret the data correctly.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. I have tried this in a multitude of different ways, all of which fail. The closest I've gotten to getting this API call to work is when the debugger tells me "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html". And the AJAX call errors out with my debug message that dumps the jqXHR object in JSON format, which tells me: `{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"parsererror"}`

Here is an example of my code (although I have changed the code many various ways, in my attempts at getting it to work, but this version seems to be the closest to correct):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://username:api-key@www.kanbanpad.com/api/v1/projects.json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    converters: {
        'jsonp': jQuery.parseJSON,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
        console.log(textStatus+': '+errorThrown);
    }
});
```

If anyone can figure out what I need to do differently to make this work, I will be extremely grateful.

**It may also be worth noting that if you copy/paste the API URL into a browser address bar and hit go, it gives the proper JSON response with the proper response header ("application/json")**

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `dataType: "html"`, and then parse it in success?

Comment: Absolutely. If I do that, I get a origin error. This is a cross-domain request, don't forget, so `dataType` pretty much has to be `jsonp` or `json` with a `callback=?` on the URL which just makes jQuery convert it to `jsonp` automatically. I also tried adding `callback=?` while dataType = `html`, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you post the response that your server is sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unless Kanbanpad updates their API, it cannot be directly accessed with JS. You will have to use PHP (or some other) to handle the requests.

It works just as well, it just requires an extra step is all.

Just for anyone that was looking for a solution.

Comment: This problem is related to the `JSON` library and not kanbanpad.

Comment: False. The problem **IS** that Kanbanpad is using JSON, which is not cross-domain. This is why proxying requests through PHP is necessary. They should be using JSONP or some other CORS style API which facilitate cross-domain XHR.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dataFilter(data, type)Function
    A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest.
This is a pre-filtering
function to sanitize the response. You should return the sanitized data. The function
accepts two arguments: The raw data returned from the server and the 'dataType' parameter.
```

I would change the content type in the dataFilter interceptor to json. Bear in mind this affects all ajax calls, so use info from *data* to decide which ones you want to convert.

Comment: I tried adding  `dataFilter: function(data, type) { return JSON.stringify(data); },` in the AJAX call, but I still get the same MIME type error.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your server is sending a jsonp response.  This means the json should be enclosed with a string of your callback.

The callback name is passed in the parameters, and if you're not setting it explicitly, looks something like: **jQuery15102810791094068532_1300988427891**  (As per http://www.json-p.org/)

On your server, you need to format the response:

```
jQuery15102810791094068532_1300988427891({...json response ...});
```

Where you use the callback defined in your GET parameter 'callback'.

You might try setting the type to "json" and see if it works.  I've had a number of parsererror's with the jquery's jsonp - you might try http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp until it's a bit smoother.

Comment: Thanks for the canned response. Please actually read the question before answering.

Comment: @theRealKlanni - It wasn't a canned response - you've got your dataType set to 'jsonp' not 'json'.  If you're getting back only json, then your server is not sending jsonp... which will cause the error you're receiving.  The text you should get back should look like:  "mycallbackfunction({"parameter1": 0, "parameter2": "1"})" ... if it's returning text like "{"parameter1": 0, "parameter2": "1"}" - then your server needs to add the mycallbackfunction to your response.

Comment: Can you modify the response from the server's end?

Comment: If you can't modify the response from the server's end, then you need another way around same-origin-policy... you can write a small php script locally on your website's local server that will get the json and pass it back to your webpage.

Comment: I was considering doing that. I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your content-type to this

```
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. I'm not even sure why you think that would help.